# IIS redirect only one domain on SSL

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis

I have some website on IIS that was http, but now i have added the SSL, but only for one domain. But i have a lot of custom domain that poits to same website, this is what i need

Have ssl for **www.example.com** and **example.com**, but i also have **www.examplenew.com, www.example34.com, example56.com** that points to same website but i dont have ssl for them, i only need rewrite rule for www.example.com and example.com other i dont need.
I have made rewrite rule in web.config, for redirect to https but know its redirect all to ssl i dont need that, this is my **web.config** file

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(*)" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an additional condition to rewrite rule, which will check host:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example.com" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```